# Disable calltip boxes in Idle

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm using Idle, and these yellow calltip boxes keep popping out whenever I enter an open parenthesis. It's helpful, but can be annoying. Is there anyway I can disable them?
[Image of Yellow Suggestion Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXtP5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The boxes are function call tips giving the needed arguments and a short description of what the function does and returns.  They only appear when Python's syntax rules say that one must be making a function call, rather than performing some other operation.  For example, `a * (b+c)` does not result in a calltip.  AFAIK, the current code that makes the determination is correct.

There is currently no way to suppress them.  If more people complain, I will consider adding one.  But the problem is that there is no way for IDLE to know if you need the calltip or not.  And everyone who uses more than a small set of functions will find the tip helpful sometimes.